# Outlook tasks wont delete

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, task-manager, tasks

I have a few tasks that don't seem to want to delete. I can try hitting the flag button for completion, remove any reoccurances, and even remove from list or delete, but they keep poping back in to my task panel after a few minutes.

When I am on the "To-Do List" option, they are shown in my task list, but when I choose the "Tasks" option they are gone. However, they never go away in my expanded tool-bar or when I am in calendar view.

[image]

Any help would be great!

Comment: To which mailserver is your Outlook connected? Is this a corporate installation using Exchange Server?

Comment: It's a university exchange server (although I have other IMAP accounts on my Outlook). However, they seem to sync up to my laptop which my IMAP accounts can't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have actually figured out my problem:

Although I do have an exchange account, the tasks that kept popping up where not associated with that account. Instead, I looked through my other IMAP accounts in the delete folder and ended up finding them there. Once I deleted the files from that folder the tasks deleted for good and I haven't seen them since!